# react-dropzone - accessing files added by click not drop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, react-dropzone

I am using the react-dropzone basic example ([react-dropzone basic](https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone/tree/master/examples/basic))

```
import React from 'react';
import {useDropzone} from 'react-dropzone';

function Basic(props) {
  const {acceptedFiles, getRootProps, getInputProps} = useDropzone();

  const files = acceptedFiles.map(file => (
    <li key={file.path}>
      {file.path} - {file.size} bytes
    </li>
  ));

  return (
    <section className="container">
      <div {...getRootProps({className: 'dropzone'})}>
        <input {...getInputProps()} />
        <p>Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
      </div>
      <aside>
        <h4>Files</h4>
        <ul>{files}</ul>
      </aside>
    </section>
  );
}

<Basic />
```

This is working as expected, until I use the click method to add a file. When adding a file using click the `acceptedFiles` do not register the file (I have added an onChange handler and event.target.files shows the file so it is defintely being added to the overall `FileList`).

Due to this I cannot display the file added by click details in the `Files <ul>` as I would with a dragged file. I assume the same would be true for `fileRejections` but I have not implemented it yet.

I hope I'm missing something obvious as I would assume that dropzone handles both drag and click behaviour?

Appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above code handles both drag and drop, however it only gives you the latest added files and not the entire list of uploaded file.

To implement it correctly you can maintain a state and add an onDrop function to useDropzone in which you will append the files and update state

```
function Basic(props) {
  const [files, setFiles] = React.useState([]);
  const onDrop = React.useCallback(acceptedFiles => {
    setFiles(prev => [...prev, ...acceptedFiles]);
  }, []);
  const { getRootProps, getInputProps } = useDropzone({ onDrop });

  const fileList = files.map(file => (
    <li key={file.path}>
      {file.path} - {file.size} bytes
    </li>
  ));

  return (
    <section className="container">
      <div {...getRootProps({ className: "dropzone" })}>
        <input {...getInputProps()} />
        <p>Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
      </div>
      <aside>
        <h4>Files</h4>
        <ul>{fileList}</ul>
      </aside>
    </section>
  );
}
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-dropzone-3o10l?file=/src/index.js:132-835)

Comment: can I ask how you would handle a rejected file using `onDrop` here?

Comment: You could use two separate function like onDropAccepted and onDropRejected instead of onDrop. Check the documentation for details: https://react-dropzone.js.org/

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in your code. You just need to properly click on the div.

Just add bit of style to the drag and drop area so that the drop zone is clear to both drop as well as click.

[working demo is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-drag-and-drop-issue-fix-tqyxm?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/Basic.js)

```js
export default function Basic(props) {
  const { acceptedFiles, getRootProps, getInputProps } = useDropzone();

  const files = acceptedFiles.map(file => (
    <li key={file.path}>
      {file.path} - {file.size} bytes
    </li>
  ));

  return (
    <section className="container">
      <div
        style={{
          cursor: "pointer",
          background: "gray",
          height: "200px",
          border: "2px dashed blue"
        }}
        {...getRootProps({ className: "dropzone" })}
      >
        <input {...getInputProps()} />
        <p>Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
      </div>
      <aside>
        <h4>Files</h4>
        <ul>{files}</ul>
      </aside>
    </section>
  );
}
```